# How to build a template for data exchange using JSON?

Tags: json

I need to build a template for data exchange between two web services using JSON. I believe I need to build a JSON template  which could be similar to XSD used in XML. Is that right?

Please guide me to a good tutorial or a good app to generate a JSON template.

Thanks on advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called JSON schema. Have a look at [wikipedia's page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Schema)

If you want a schema generator, then look at the [answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341537/tool-to-generate-json-schema-from-json-data).