# How to generate JSON data samples, given JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

There are different online tools for inferring JSON schema, given JSON data sample. For example, [JSON Schema Tool](https://www.jsonschema.net/).
However, I need to do the opposite thing. I have a schema. How can I generate data samples, given this schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate sample Json output from Json Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894873/generate-sample-json-output-from-json-schema)