JSON schema to VB.Net results in non-working code for collections
Never having worked with Newtonsoft before, I read many threads here and found that producing the model object should be easy: use one of the many online tools to convert the schema to VB.net (or C# and convert). My attempts to do so have all failed, that also includes using a pure C# conversion. The issue has to do with collections (I think) or maybe just the schema file itself.
The original schema is 3500 lines, here's a snippet (it's NDA so I don't know how much I can post). This is right near the top, it's part of the definition of the root object:
"properties": {
    "Properties": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Property"
      }
    }

And then later in the code is a definition of the Property object, which is basically just a bunch of strings:
"Property": {
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "Name",
    "Location",
    "ID",
    "ObjectType"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "Messages": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Message"
      }
    },
    "Name": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/$basicType/definitions/requiredString"
    },
    "Location": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/$basicType/definitions/requiredString"
    },
    ... more of same...

I read this as the root JSON has a structure called "Properties" that is an array of Property objects, which has a Messages collection (which are just strings) and then a bunch of fields. Looking at a sample file of the output JSON, I see a single object in the collection (as expected):
"Properties":[{"ID":"33...

First up, I tried jsonutils.com, as it has direct JSON->VB. That produced this:
Public Class Items
    Public Property $ref As String
End Class

Public Class Properties
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property minItems As Integer
    Public Property uniqueItems As Boolean
    Public Property items As Items
End Class

Public Class Properties
    Public Property Version As Version
    Public Property Messages As Messages
    Public Property Properties As Properties
End Class

....

Public Class Property
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property required As String()
    Public Property properties As Properties
End Class

Among the many issues, it defined two classes called Properties. Moreover, the list, items, is not a collection of Property objects but a reference to a new class called Items which is a ref to a Properties, which doesn't refer to Property objects. This is not the only instance of an items collection in the schema, and it converted them all to Items despite them pointing to different underlying objects.
Next up, I tried the alternative suggestion of making a C# version using JSON2Csharp (now THAT's funny, it autocorrected to "shart"!), and then converting that. Realizing the two-step process was unlikely to work out of the box, I instead made a new C# project and put the results in there. This too gave me many lines like...
public Items items { get; set; }

But this time it didn't bother to make an Items class at all, so these are just errors.
OK, questions:

does anyone know of a tool that properly handles this sort of JSON schema? I assume it's the $ or # that's confusing it? I saw many references to various downloadable tools, but I can no longer find any of them online.

failing that, I suspect I simply have to convert the various items references to a collection type, but I'm not familiar with NS, so are these simply List(Of Property) or does it expect some other type during deserialization?



Paste your JSON in QuickType, pick first Attributes Only in the Output Features selector. You'll see that all JSON Properties are decorated with attributes that map the name of JSON Properties to .NET / C# compliant names. Go from there. The Complete version of the parser also includes code for some basic converters, if these appear to be needed (sometimes, also when they're not :). But this also can give you some hints on how to parse the original JSON -- Without the actual - complete - structure, suggesting something meaningful is not that easy

I think the problem is that "paste your JSON"... I have a JSON schema file, not the JSON itself. Is there something that converts the schema file to a class layout?

I get that, but, as mentioned, the schema is incomplete, it's not clear what you're going to use it for or whether it contains external references (other files). See Loading Schemas and the Resolving externally referenced schemas section - Are you planning on using the schema to create the class structure of the actual JSON preemptively? Or for validation purposes?

Are you using .NET or .NET Framework? What version?

The following may be of interest: How to write .NET objects as JSON (serialize)

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. Ensure to include valid (ie: complete) JSON, not snippets. The JSON should be representative of the JSON you're working with and be valid. Use an online validator, such as JSON Beautify, to validate your JSON prior to posting it.

Have you tried using Visual Studio to create the classes? In Visual Studio add a class to your project, copy the JSON to the clipboard (Ctrl-C), then in Visual Studio menu, Edit => Paste Special => Paste JSON As Classes

For some example JSON, see here.

@user246821 - again, I have the JSON schema not the JSON. Those tools only work on the JSON.

@Jimi - yes, I want to use the schema file to generate the model classes. There are no external references or anything slightly "odd", its really just a collection of structures containing numbers, strings and pointers to other structures. The schema lists all of the fields and their types, it should be possible to use it to generate a model classes, no? Am I missing something here?

@user246821 - JSON schemas are written in JSON.

@MauryMarkowitz: Sorry, my mistake.

You may try searching for: create json from json schema. If you're able to generate some sample JSON, then you can use Visual Studio to create the classes. The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664260/10024425

Google, having failed to turn up anything useful, did point me to the JSON Schema discord. A post there turns up the answer to this thread:
corvus-dotnet/Corvus.JsonSchema
Personally I would have preferred to use an online tool, but having installed this tool it immediately produced a working object model and I'll definitely recommend it to everyone.
For those of you wondering, the advantage to using the schema file (aside from that being all I had) is that it contains much more metadata that is absolutely useful... things like which fields are required and which are optional, the types of the objects in an array, etc. These flesh out the object model much more than using an actual JSON file.
