# How to create a json-schema out of a json object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, json-schema-defaults

Given a browser debugger output of root.value with two properties in javascript

```
root.value
__proto__: {...}
firstname: "my name"
age: 25
```

I want to parse it to a JSON string including the type like below. Or literally convert the above json object to the format below.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "title": "Basic Info",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
       "firstName": {
           "type": "string"
         },
         "age": {
           "type": "number"
     }
   }
 }
```

Does any one know how to do that in javascript or any framework I can use to achieve such?

Note: I did not created the JSON myself it's an output of another framework. So the types of the fields are unknown until runtime.

My main concern is to embed the json object values for

```
{ "properties": {
      "firstName": {
         "type": "string"
       },
       "age": {
         "type": "number"
       }
}


 JSON.stringify(root.value);
```

will only return

```
{
   {
       "firstname":" my name"
   },
   {
        "age": 25
   }   
 }
```

Comment: Does this purely have to happen on the client side?  ie.  using javascript?  or do/would you have server side code involved? and what language?

Comment: I am not validating, I am parsing. Thanks

Comment: Realized, thus I deleted it :)

Comment: Anyhow, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341537/tool-to-generate-json-schema-from-json-data

Comment: Yes on client side using javascript

Comment: I literally want to convert  the said json object into this format

Comment: {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "title": "Basic Info",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
       "firstName": {
           "type": "string"
         },
         "age": {
           "type": "number"
     }
   }
 }

Comment: Go to this page http://json-schema.org/implementations.html, go down to the bottom and click on 'Other'. I think that may be what you are looking for. Presumably you want some kind of automatic converter.

Comment: Thanks I'll try http://orderly-json.org/ if it will help solving my problem.